# Relationship between VC dimension and degrees of freedom

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

I'm studying machine learning and I feel there is a strong relationship between the concept of VC dimension and the more classical (statistical) concept of degrees of freedom.

Can anyone explain such a connection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated by Prof Yaser Abu-Mostafa-

> Degrees of freedom are an abstraction of the effective number of parameters. The effective number is based on how many [dichotomies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomy) one can get, rather than how many real-valued parameters are used. In the case of 2-dimensional perceptron, one can think of slope and intercept (plus a binary degree of freedom for which region goes to +1), or one can think of 3 parameters w_0,w_1,w_2 (though the weights can be simultaneously scaled up or down without affecting the resulting hypothesis). The degrees of freedom, however, are 3 because we have the flexibility to shatter 3 points, not because of one way or another of counting the number of parameters.

[image: 2-d perceptron]

Comment: I think this is a quite non-standard definition of degrees of freedom!

Answer (score 0):

The VC dimension is very well explained in [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67119/svmtutorial.pdf) in Section 2.1 and further, with the basic lemmas and proofs given. You can go through this.